# React, this.setState always returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, setstate, json-server

while following this guide (
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ied4aZxUzc&t=1619s) I ran into a problem with `this.setState()` always returning `undefined`.

The IP in the following code requests from my `json-server` app and a promise is successfully returned. However the value of state is always `undefined`.

```
componentDidMount() 
 const uri = 'http://192.168.1.220:3000/Songs';
      fetch(uri, {
                 method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                             "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Accept": "application/json"
                            },
     })
    .then((response) => {
               return response.json()
              })
    .then(json => {
               console.log(json);
               this.setState({songs: json});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
               console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error)
    });
```

I have tried to solve by: turning off cors, calling static methods outside `componentDidMount()`, and passing state to a constructor, using `.bind(this)` on then statements.

Comment: The wording seems to be incorrect. It's the state that is undefined, not setState return value, isn't it? The code is ok. It should set the state or log an error - unless the request is pending. If `setState` is called, the state cannot physically be undefined. Are there any logs? How do you check that the state is undefined? Most likely you have problems with the rest of this component. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Posted code can't help to replicate the problem.

Comment: You may should post your details about your problem.Like,which line  is your problem exactly and what is the result about "console.log(json)".If it's a problem about setState,the setState don't have return value, and I guess your value of json is undefined, so please update your question.

Comment: I can't edit the question. But state is declared like this: state = {songs:[]}; before the componentDidMount(). Logging the setState returns undefined, and the div tag that is surposed to display it is blank. Logging the json returns a list with three json objects (as desired).